# Multiply two Galois field arrays that do not result in zero

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, matrix-equations

I need a vector V=[a1,a2,a3,...,a16] such that for every vector X=[x1,x2,x3,...,x16] the product P=V.X=a1.x1+a2.x2+a3.x3+...+a16.x16 is not equal to zero. except zero vector.

where a1,a2,...,a16, x1,x2,...,x16 belongs to Galois field GF(2^8). and both the product and addition coincides with the Galois field GF(2^8).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: No can do. For every $V$ you can choose $X=(a_2,a_1,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$. Or, more abstractly, the vectors orthogonal to a given vector of a 16-dimensional space form a 15-dimensional subspace, so there will be lots of non-zero vectors to choose from.

Comment: If it is easier for you think in $\Bbb{R}^3$, you are asking for a vector that isn't orthogonal to anything other than the zero vector. Not gonna happen. The moral: *linear algebra works (mostly) the same over any field*.

Comment: Thank you for the help @JyrkiLahtonen